# IE closes tabs on lock

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, lock

When I lock my user account and reopen, all Internet Explorer pages are automatically closed.

It's only IE, all other applications work fine.

What I tried:

1. Temp deleted
2. Reset IE
3. IE upgrade from 8 to 11
4. Profile recreated

Comment: i spend hours and hour on google but i dint find any solution for this  please help me

Comment: Do you have IE set to restore your previous session?

Comment: check event viewer

Comment: that also i tried

Comment: # seanctl : am not find nothing unusual but its normally working  on other user account

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a task in your taskscheduler.

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Type (or copy): **Taskschd.msc** and press enter

Click on your library and check all the tasks. By default there should be around 5-10 tasks. First try to disable all of them (don't delete, just disable).

After disabling them, try to logout and log back in. If IE is still opened, narrow the problem down and see which of the tasks is creating this problem.

Comment: it because of some authentication